# I'm upgrading the Vuetify version from 1.5 to 2.0, but the previously installed plugin is no longer visible in the project

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js, vuex

old vuetify plugins not showing, but new vuetify plugins appear.v-checkbox as an example.
can you help me

[v-checkbox is not visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPub5.png)

```
   **Vuetify JS
```

After 2.0 update**

```js
       // v2.0
// src/plugins/vuetify.js
// follow official document
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib';
Vue.use(Vuetify);
export default new Vuetify({
    dark: true, // it's decide your project 
    themes: {
        light: {
            prime: '#df8421'
        },
        dark: {
            prime: '#333'
        }
    },
    icons: {
        iconfont: 'mdi',
    },
});
```

> After 2.0 update main js  Is there anything wrong here
> I saw that there was no problem when I checked the documents?

```js
 import Vue from 'vue'
    import './plugins/vuetify'
    import store from './store/store'
    import router from './router'
    import Axios from 'axios'
    import BootstrapVue from "bootstrap-vue"
    import App from './App'
    import Default from './components/Wrappers/baseLayout.vue';
    import VueFuse from 'vue-fuse'
    import 'vue-search-select/dist/VueSearchSelect.css'
    import Antd from 'ant-design-vue';
    import 'ant-design-vue/dist/antd.css';
    import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify';
    Vue.use(Antd);
    
    Vue.prototype.$http = Axios;
    export const actionArea = new Vue()
    export const noteArea = new Vue()
    export const noteRedboxList = new Vue()
    export const statusArea = new Vue()
    export const TicketTransferDialog = new Vue()
    export const TicketStatusArea = new Vue()
    export const cancelReason = new Vue()
    export const docDetail = new Vue()
    
    
    
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
    if (token) {
        Vue.prototype.$http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = token
    }
    
    
    
    Vue.config.productionTip = false;
    
    Vue.use(BootstrapVue);
    Vue.use(VueFuse);
    
    Vue.component('default-layout', Default);
    //Vue.component('userpages-layout', Pages);
    //Vue.component('apps-layout', Apps);
    //Vue.component('empty-layout', Empty);
    
    
    new Vue({
        vuetify,
        el: '#app',
        router,
        store,
        template: '<App/>',
        components: { App },
        mounted() {
            //console.log('token',localStorage.getItem('token'));
            if (localStorage.getItem('token')) {
                // store.dispatch('getSystemTexts',(e)=>{})
            }
        }
    });

**My package Json**
```

I updated all versions, but there was no solution. Node deletes modules and goes to vuetify

```js
{
  "name": "architectui-vue-pro",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "^11.2.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue": "^1.0.0-beta.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.17",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.8.1",
    "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome": "^0.1.6",
    "@fullcalendar/core": "^5.3.1",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^5.3.2",
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "^5.3.1",
    "@fullcalendar/list": "^5.3.1",
    "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "^5.3.1",
    "@fullcalendar/vue": "^5.3.1",
    "@smartweb/vue-flash-message": "^0.6.4",
    "animate-sass": "^0.8.2",
    "ant-design-vue": "^1.6.5",
    "antd": "^4.7.0",
    "apexcharts": "^3.6.7",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.0.0-rc.18",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.3",
    "core-js": "^2.6.11",
    "countup.js": "^1.9.3",
    "dayspan": "^1.1.0",
    "dayspan-vuetify": "^0.4.0",
    "es6-promise": "^4.2.6",
    "gantt-schedule-timeline-calendar": "^2.6.8",
    "increase-memory-limit": "^1.0.6",
    "kalendar-vue": "^2.1.1",
    "leaflet": "^1.4.0",
    "linearicons": "^1.0.1",
    "material-design-icons-iconfont": "^4.0.5",
    "mockjs": "^1.0.1-beta3",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "pe7-icon": "^1.0.4",
    "perfect-scrollbar": "^1.4.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.15.0",
    "portal-vue": "^2.1.7",
    "qs": "^6.8.0",
    "quill": "^1.3.7",
    "sweetalert": "^2.1.2",
    "sweetalert2": "^8.19.0",
    "toastr": "^2.1.4",
    "v-mask": "^1.3.4",
    "v-select2-component": "^0.4.3",
    "vee-validate": "^2.2.3",
    "vue": "^2.6.10",
    "vue-apexcharts": "^1.5.3",
    "vue-cal": "^3.6.4",
    "vue-chartjs": "^3.5.0",
    "vue-clipboards": "^1.2.4",
    "vue-color": "^2.7.0",
    "vue-country-flag": "^1.1.0",
    "vue-countup-v2": "^2.0.0",
    "vue-cropperjs": "^3.0.0",
    "vue-element-loading": "^1.1.1",
    "vue-form-wizard": "^0.8.4",
    "vue-full-calendar": "^2.8.0",
    "vue-fuse": "^2.1.0",
    "vue-good-wizard": "^1.4.1",
    "vue-js-toggle-button": "^1.3.3",
    "vue-json-excel": "^0.2.98",
    "vue-ladda": "0.0.15",
    "vue-mask-directive": "^1.0.4",
    "vue-moment": "^4.1.0",
    "vue-multiselect": "^2.1.6",
    "vue-notifications": "^0.9.0",
    "vue-perfect-scrollbar": "^0.1.0",
    "vue-quill-editor": "^3.0.6",
    "vue-rate": "^2.2.0",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.5",
    "vue-search-select": "^2.9.3",
    "vue-select": "^2.6.4",
    "vue-sidebar-menu": "^3.7.0",
    "vue-simple-alert": "^1.1.1",
    "vue-simple-file-upload": "^1.2.5",
    "vue-slick": "^1.1.15",
    "vue-slider-component": "^2.8.16",
    "vue-sparklines": "^0.1.9",
    "vue-spinkit": "^1.4.1",
    "vue-sticky-directive": "0.0.8",
    "vue-sweetalert2": "^3.0.5",
    "vue-tabs-with-active-line": "^1.1.4",
    "vue-textarea-autosize": "^1.0.4",
    "vue-timeselector": "^1.0.0",
    "vue-toastr": "^2.0.16",
    "vue2-animate": "^2.1.0",
    "vue2-circle-progress": "^1.2.3",
    "vue2-datepicker": "^2.11.0",
    "vue2-dropzone": "^3.5.8",
    "vue2-google-maps": "^0.10.6",
    "vue2-leaflet": "^1.2.3",
    "vuejs-datepicker": "^1.6.2",
    "vuelidate": "^0.7.5",
    "vuetable-2": "^2.0.0-beta.4",
    "vuetify": "^2.3.21",
    "vuetrend": "^0.3.2",
    "vuex": "^3.1.0",
    "vuex-persistedstate": "^2.5.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@mdi/font": "^5.6.55",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.6.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^3.6.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.6.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.2.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "sass": "^1.30.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.3.1",
    "stylus": "^0.54.5",
    "stylus-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "^0.5.0",
    "vue-friendly-iframe": "^0.18.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10",
    "vuetify-loader": "^1.0.5"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "rules": {},
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    }
  },
  "postcss": {
    "plugins": {
      "autoprefixer": {}
    }
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As seen in the [installation docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/installation/#webpack-install), the Vuetify setup must import the styles (which is missing from your setup):

```js
// src/plugins/vuetify.js
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'
```

Also make sure to update your `index.html` to install the required [fonts and icons](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/installation/#font-installation):

```html
<!-- public/index.html -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```